# What are the limitations of Trusted Platform Modules?

Tags: macos, kernel

Apple introduced DMCA measures (like [DSMOS](https://www.lightbulbone.com/posts/2016/10/dsmos-kext/) and [CPUID Validation](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/0a798f6738bc1db01281fc08ae024145e84df927/osfmk/i386/cpuid.c#L830)) instead of attempting to utilize a Trusted Platform Module [(which was physically present on hardware but did not have drivers on Mac OS X)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120922012421/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/tpm/#EXECUTIVE_SUMMARY).

What are the limitations that Trusted Platform Modules have that don't make them a viable solution (or less ideal solution) for platform lockdown?

Comment: Questions about why Apple does or doesn't do things are off-topic as only Apple can answer them (and they usually don't).

Comment: That is understandable, thank you! DSMOS can be bypassed using tools like `FakeSMC` (or any other `SMC` emulation tool) and I was wondering why they wouldn't use iPhone-style hardware lockdown. I was hoping for a technical answer, but oh well!

Comment: In the [help center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) this is written as "specific questions about what Apple [did|does|thinks|might do] are not helpful in a Q&A setting since they lack a practical problem to be solved." so if the question can be rewritten to focus on a practical problem it might be reopened.

Comment: question has been rewritten to center around TPMs